# Command to get L2 Cache size of Sparc and x86 processor with Solaris

Tags: unix, solaris

what is the command to know the L2 cache size of CPU on Solaris operating system running on Sparc and x86 processors.

Comment: Have you considered asking this at http://unix.stackexchange.com?

Comment: I was not aware that such site exist. I will take care in future.

Comment: on Sparc machine. Following is the output       % /usr/sbin/prtpicl -v -c cpu | grep cache-size
  :ecache-size   0x800000
  :icache-size   0x8000
  :dcache-size   0x10000
  :ecache-size   0x800000
  :icache-size   0x8000
  :dcache-size   0x10000
How to interpret above output

Answer (score 1):

I don't have access to a Solaris box to test this out, but you might be able to achieve this using [prtpicl](http://www.manpages.info/sunos/prtpicl.1.html).

```
prtpicl -v -c cpu | grep l2-cache-size
```

For a more portable option, check out the [lstopo](http://www.open-mpi.org/projects/hwloc/doc/v1.3.1/#cli_examples) command from the [hwloc](http://www.open-mpi.org/projects/hwloc/) project.

Comment: yes. o/p of above command is quite lengthy. I need to figure out how get aggregate of all.                :l2-cache-line-size    0x40
  :l2-cache-size         0x80000
  :l2-cache-associativity        0x10
  :l2-cache-lines-per-tag        0x1
  :l2-cache-line-size    0x40
  :l2-cache-size         0x80000
  :l2-cache-associativity        0x10
  :l2-cache-lines-per-tag        0x1
  :l2-cache-line-size    0x40
  :l2-cache-size         0x80000
  :l2-cache-associativity        0x10
  :l2-cache-lines-per-tag        0x1
  :l2-cache-line-size    0x40
  :l2-cache-size         0x80000

Comment: @sushilkumar I'm guessing you only need "l2-cache-size" (updated answer). You'll probably get one output per CPU on the host machine.

Answer (score 0):

On sparc just run fpversion (/product/SUNWspro/bin/fpversion) and it will print the xcache code-generation options that show the L1 and L2 cache sizes.  Then read http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19205-01/819-5267/bkazt/index.html to understand it.